# PHP counter, get count number

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have set up a php counter which is inserted into a webpage which is on a altogether different server/website by using a script element and setting parameters on the url. the count files are saved as PARAMETER.txt . how can i retrieve the count number and insert it onto the external webpage? i have tried loading the txt files using jQuery $.ajax $.get etc however they don't work. how can I get the count number either from the php file with the unique paramter or from the txt file?

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$post = $_REQUEST['post']; 
if (!is_dir($id)) {
    mkdir($id);
}
if (!empty($post)) {
    if(!file_exists($id.'/'.$post.'.txt')) { 
        $fp = fopen($id.'/'.$post.'.txt',"w");  
        fwrite($fp,"1");  
        fclose($fp); 
    } else {
        $hit_count = @file_get_contents($id.'/'.$post.'.txt');
        echo $hit_count;
        $hit_count++;
        @file_put_contents($id.'/'.$post.'.txt', $hit_count);
    }
} else {
    echo "no post id";
}  
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to add your code?

Comment: sorry :/ completely forgot :P

Comment: Does the PHP work when you call it directly? What exactly is the error message you're getting?

Comment: [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and drop the error supression.

Comment: when i reload the page on my second website the counter does increase by +1 each time, the problem i am having is I don't know how to retrieve that number on the second website and insert it

Comment: why don't you echo it back as a javascript variable?

Comment: just above `} else {` add `echo "var counter='{$hit_count}';";`

Comment: If the problem is cross-origin AJAX requests, you should look into JSONP or the Allow-Origin headers. Typically, the browser (and so, jQuery et al) will not allow `http://somewhere` to request resources from `http://elsewhere` as a security measure. If you have control of both, you can allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this on a university computer. This 'error' seems to be due to how the server is configured. Your code returns a number as expected on my own apache, but when I do the same thing on the remote host, the response is 200 ok, but there is nothing in the response text. My guess is that your server is not configured to respond to external calls like that.